# Side scroll image, but the image changes

Tags: javascript, css

I have a header that has a css background image that I want to be side-scrolled at a rate of 1px every 50ms. However, the background image changes depending on the time on the users computer and I cannot work out how I would go about doing this. I did write the code for the side-scrolling itself, but nothing else.

The Javascript used to side-scroll (nothing else):

```
setInterval("mvheader()",50);
function mvheader () {
window.cssXPos=window.cssXPos+1;
if (window.cssXPos>=window.cssMaxWidth) {
window.cssXPos=0;
}
toMove=document.getElementById("header");
toMove.style.backgroundPosition=window.cssXPos+"px 0px";
}
```

The JavaScript used to use a different css file depending on the time:

```
function styleSwitcher() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
  if (0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 6) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/night.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  if (6 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 18) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/day.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
  if (18 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 24) {
   document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/night.css' type='text/css'>");
  }
}

styleSwitcher();
```

The CSS (the only difference bewteen the other files is the folder name. night instead of day and vise versa):

```
#header {
background-image:url(../img/day/tile.png);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
position:absolute;
height:100px;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:9;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? Scrolling isn't working? Or does it work as expected but changing stylesheets does not? Where do you invoke `styleSwitcher()` function? Side question: is there a special reason for caching cssXPos in the window object?

Comment: The scrolling doesn't work. The `styleSwitcher()` function runs from the same JavaScript file, as the function is in.

Comment: @WTK As for the side question, I just thought it would increase performance.

Comment: Ok, in general it looks like a simple task (scrolling + changing css based on time of the day). I'll look into it tomorrow unless someone will help you over night :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, so there were couple of problems with your side-scrolling script:

- running the mvheader function before the document was loaded (I'm assuming your code was in external js file)
- using expression: `setInterval("mvheader()", 50)` it would work as expected, however using that syntax boils down to fact, that javascript has to interpret string passed as a first arguemnt. You can use `setInterval(mvheader, 50)` as an equivalent - as you can see, you would now pass function as a parameter to *setInterval*
- not using "var" keyword when defining toMove variable - it wouldn't work as expected in IE
- polluting global scope (window object) with additional variables cssXPos and cssMaxWidth

I've modified your code and you can check working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/wtk_pl/ydJhr/4/.

It's working fine, however I've also created seconds, cleaner version that don't pollute global scope with new variables and should perform better because I "cache" the `#header` node in a variable, rather than searching for it on every iteration of a `mvheader()`. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/wtk_pl/ydJhr/9/

As to loading different css based on time of the day - It's totally doable from javascript, however I would recommend you do that on server side (meaning determine and embed proper css file before sending page content to user) - why bother the client side script with that?

Comment: The theme was supposed to change depending on the users time. But I suppose I could do something with GeoIP and get the timezone of the user then send them the correct css file.